# How to save/get an access token to/from a specific keychain access group

Tags: ios, objective-c

How can I save a JSON web token to a specific keychain access group and how can I retrieve this token from the keychain using Objective-c? (I want to do this without using any keychain wrapper.)

Comment: Then best way is to store your token into NSUserDefault.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can indeed store/retrieve/delete values in the Keychain using the C API Apple provides. But first, I want to clarify the answers you have already received: storing the JWT in the User Defaults is completely discouraged as anything stored there is treated as plain text and compromises your data/API security.

You can verify this by yourself by accessing the app's bundle through the FileManager and locating the preferences.plist if I recall well.

Now, back to your question, I can provide some help but I'm missing the part to access the specific keychain access group, should not be complicated though...

So, this steps summarize the generic use of the Keychain:

- As the keychain is a SQLite3 DB, you need to start by creating a query.
- There's NO check for duplicates when you store something there, so you would need to remove the current item before adding a new one just to keep things in place, if the item you are trying to remove doesn't exists it does nothing.
- Add the item, (query) to the KeyChain.

Here is an example in Swift, understand it so you can easily translate it to ObjC:

```
// value is anything you want to store, let's say "Hello Jobs", and you need to
convert that value to data.

if let valueData = value.data(using: .utf8) {
        return [kSecClass as String: kSecClassGenericPassword as String,
                kSecAttrAccount as String: key,
                kSecValueData as String: valueData] as [String:Any]
    }

SecItemDelete(query as CFDictionary) // Delete the query if exists
SecItemAdd(query as CFDictionary, nil) // Store your value
```

As you can see you need to cast the queries as CFDictionary as thats the expected type the C API is receiving as a parameter.

Now to retrieve the stored value you need to do something as follows:

```
// You need a query again, but this time you add extra parameters to indicate you want to return the value as data using the boolean below and to limit the query to just 1 item.
let query = [kSecClass as String: kSecClassGenericPassword as String,
                 kSecAttrAccount as String: key,
                 kSecReturnData as String: kCFBooleanTrue,
                 kSecMatchLimit as String: kSecMatchLimitOne] as [String: Any]

// You define a var to use its reference (memory address) as its required by the SecItemCopyMatching API so it can store the outcome of the query there.
    var dataTypeRef: AnyObject?
    let status: OSStatus = SecItemCopyMatching(query as CFDictionary, &dataTypeRef)
    if status == noErr {
        return dataTypeRef as? Data // If the query was successful you retrieve the data by casting your previously defined var to a Data type
    }
```

The only thing left to do here is to convert the retrieved Data value to whatever you need to, in this case it would be a String as thats the type of your JWT.

Hope you can use this as a guide, my bet is that you need to add one extra value to the query in order to use the specific keychain group you want to fetch the data from.

Answer (score 0):

To save a token to a specific keychain access group, you first need to create that keychain access group in your Apple Developer console, associated with your app id.  Then, give your app id the entitlement of accessing that access group.  This should give you an entitlements file that looks something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" 
"http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>keychain-access-groups</key>
    <array>
        <string>656CMN2Q97.com.mycompany.myapp</string>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Then, reading and writing to it is as simple as this:

```
NSString *kapiToken = @"apiToken";
NSString *kServices = @"Services";

self.apiToken = [UICKeyChainStore stringForKey:kapiToken service:kServices];

....

[UICKeyChainStore setString:self.apiToken forKey:kapiToken service:kServices];
```